# printf hex value output seemed bigger than is should

Tags: c++, class, printf, crc32, data-integrity

I have a function that calculate a 32 bit CRC,

I have an internal variable to a class that hold the CRC.

the function that validate CRC consistency return a boolean result of the class CRC with what the class is calculating,

the member function inside the class does the next,

save the CRC into a temp variable, calculate CRC then compare the two values.

```
bool X::CRCisMatching()
{
   unsigned long tmpCRC = ClassCRC;
   ClassCRC = GetNewCalculatedCRC();
   printf("comparing %08x ~ with ~ %08x!\n", tmpCRC, ClassCRC);
   return tmpCRC == ClassCRC;
}
```

the issue is that I get this output,

`comparing AB44CD2A33 ~ with ~ AB44CD2A33`

why I am getting 10 values instead of 8 as intended with %08x

did anyone face any similar problem before??

btw, I am using a 32 bit machine

Comment: You should be using `%08lx` with a `long`.

Comment: If you want to you can shift right by 8. i.e. `tmpCRC >> 8` will give you the first 8 hexadecimal digits (likewise, `tmpCRC & 0xFF` would give you the last two if you wanted it)

Comment: why would I need to shift, I just thought a mast with 0xFFFFFFFF is enough

Answer (score 0):

Because `%08x` means a *minimum* length of 8, not maximum. And whether your machine is 32-bit or 64-bit does not necessarily control the size of a `long`. I suggest you print out  `sizeof(unsigned long)` to confirm its size.

Normally (though not guaranteed), a 32-bit systems will have a 32-bit `unsigned int`. C provides specific-width types like `uint32_t` and this is also available in C++11 via the `cstdint`  header. (assuming there's an underlying type that provides it).

My advice would be to use that type if your compiler is modern enough, otherwise, assuming that you discover `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` (and your bytes are eight bits), that's the type you should probably use.

Comment: oh so if I am getting a bigger number, it mean I am using a bad data type?? I will print out the size of long to find out tomorrow morning

Comment: @abdul, no, not necessarily a _bad_ type. You could always do your calculations modulo 2^32 but you're probably better off using one that automagically does that for you, such as `unsigned int` (though you should check the size of that as well).

Comment: I will probably adjust the data type to UINT32 which is already provided by the vendor, to be safe, and find out what happens next.

Comment: C++ does have `uint32_t` et al under the `cstdint` header.

Comment: @Rapptz, yes, just confirmed that, c++11 added those types. Adjusted answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

**sizeof(int) is not as expected** and `printf()` (or the post) is amiss.

```
printf("comparing %08x ~ with ~ %08x!\n", tmpCRC, ClassCRC);
```

OP reports this printed "comparing AB44CD2A33 ~ with ~ AB44CD2A33".  This implies that the format specifier "%08x", which is looking for an `int`, found an `int` with a value that needs more than 4 bytes to represent.  This hints that an `int` is 8 bytes.  The reported 32 bit machine suggests, but does not specify an `int` width.  Further, the `8` in `%08x` only specifies the *minimum* print width.

OP passed a `unsigned long` and the print specifier expected an `unsigned`.  I suspect this did not affect the issue supposing these 2 types are the same on OP's machine.  Good code would have used a printf specifier of `%08lx` to matched `unsigned long`.

OP reported output of "AB44CD2A33".  With a `%x` format specifier, an output of "ab44cd2a33" would be expected.  Although this may simply be a transcription error, it raises concerns that the post is errant in other places or that the compiler is not compliant.

Should the OP want to use a definite 32-bit value for the 32-bit CRC, recommend using type `uint32_t` and PRIX32 for printing.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uint32_t tmpCRC = ClassCRC;
printf("0x%" PRIX32 "\n", tmpCRC);
```